# How to get structure of a Google Protobuf message without the definition

Tags: java, data-structures, protocol-buffers

I have to get the message structure of a protobuf message transfered to me without the message's definition. Using UnknownFieldSet methods, I was able to get a string representation of the message as below:

```
1: "a"
2: {
   3:"b"
   4:"c"
}
```

What data structure does field 2 represent ? Using UnknownFieldSet.Field.getGroupList i was able to get the content of field 3 and 4, does that means field 2 has the "deprecated" group structure ?

Answer (score 3):

If you posted the raw binary data we could tell you - or you could look at the [protocol buffer encoding documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html). If you see a field with a wire type of 3, that indicates a group.

I'm not as familiar with the UnknownFieldSet API as I probably should be, but it does sound like you're dealing with a group.

On the other hand, I'd expect most of the uses of groups to be internal to Google - where did this data come from? Admittedly there's nothing to *stop* people from using the deprecated group format instead of embedded messages, but I would *hope* that few are doing so...

Is there any reason you can't ask for the .proto file involved? While *some* information can certainly be gleaned from protocol buffers without their definitions, they're really designed to be used in situations where both ends *do* know the message format - although possibly different versions.